# To create PL/SQL package with 2 procedure to create dynamic db_link based on parameters flag 0,1,2 and insert, update existing tables

Tags: plsql-package

- .procedure to create and drop dblink( flag)

  if passing 0 then create

  if passing 1 then check

  if passing 2 then drop

execute immediate 'create database link DBLINK_' || cur.SYSTEM_NAME ||
                      ' connect to BOOWNER identified by b00wnerk0j using '''|| cur.IP_ADDRESS ||':1521/XE''';

dbms_output.put_line('select 1 from dual@DBLINK_'||cur.SYSTEM_NAME||'');

--  execute immediate 'select 1 from dual@DBLINK_'||cur.SYSTEM_NAME||'' into 
vData;

-- dbms_output.put_line(vData);

--   if (vData =1) then

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Update executing..!');

else

-- DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Update not executing..!');

-- end if;

FUNCTION store_Validate_DBLINK(alink IN VARCHAR2)

RETURN NUMBER as

nCnt number;

vSql varchar2(32000);

BEGIN    vSql := 'SELECT 1  FROM dual@'||alink;    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
   vSql into nCnt;    return nCnt;    exception when others then
        return 0;

```
END store_Validate_DBLINK;
```

2.procedure     begin

for j in (select distinct loc_idnt from KOJ_CLOCKINOUT_MISSING t
   where status = 0 order by loc_idnt)   loop   call  dblink
   procedure(0);

call  dblink procedure(1);    for i in (select * from
   KOJ_CLOCKINOUT_MISSING t where status = 0  and t.loc_idnt =
   j.loc_idnt order by loc_idnt, day_dt) loop

```
begin
```

execute immediate 'insert into kojobj.KOJ_CLOCKINOUT_PULLED

select id_em,    ts_em_tm_enr,    id_str_rt,    rc_em_tm_enr,
   typ_cd_tm_enr,    mod_flag,    ts_crt_rcrd,    ts_mdf_rcrd,
   dc_dy_bsn,    sysdate       TS_WH_UPD_RCRD,    0
   WH_RCRD_PRCD_FLAG    from boowner.co_em_tm_enr@DBLINK_MIK20082  where
   ( trunc(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(yy.ts_em_tm_enr, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
                    'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS')) = i.day_dt or to_date(yy.dc_dy_bsn, 'YYYY-MM-DD') =  i.day_dt) and yy.id_str_rt =
   i.posstore ; '; end;

update KOJOBJ.KOJ_CLOCKINOUT_MISSING set  status = 1 , comments =

'Data Pulled' -- if ststus = 0 data unavailable

where poststore= i.posstore and day_dt = i.dat_dt  ;

end loop;    call  dblink procedure(2); -- dropping db_link at end

```
  end loop;
```

end;

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: hii Tad...can you help me achieve this ,if i pass 0 then create bd_link,if i pass 1 the check the db_link,if i pass 2 then drop the created db_link